# GAE site has new exception since deploy: "Cannot read property 'parsePath' of undefined"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, circleci

I've inherited a simple site with staging and production projects living on Google App Engine. Yesterday made a simple deploy to staging (using CircleCI), the first deploy since January.  Since then the site won't load and the logs show an exception we haven't had before:
"Cannot read property 'parsePath' of undefined" when trying to go to the home page at: /

Our code does not make any call to 'parsePath', so it must be some underlying machinery.

I reverted the code change and re-pushed the staging branch with the code that's been live since January (and is live and error-free right now in production), deploy was successful, but the same symptom is there still in staging! (Needless to say, we can't deploy anything to production until we know what the heck is going on)

I've been looking through the circleCI deploy logs for clues- one difference is during the "gcloud auth activate-service-account" step, it wasn't able to update the compute/zone property (but the build still succeeded):

```
Updated property [core/project].
WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [veryloudstatic] or it does not exist.
Updated property [compute/zone].
```

What should I be looking at on the GAE side?  Has anyone seen this exception before, or know enough about how GAE works to suggest places to troubleshoot? We haven't made any changes to these GAE projects in the past few months, so I'm wondering if some internal updates could be the issue?

```
Cannot read property 'parsePath' of undefined
Expand all | Collapse all {
 insertId:  "owonpfihz4box5kp7"  
 labels: {
  appengine.googleapis.com/instance_name:  "aef-default-20190620t195308-lsn2"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "2700574583511472701"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "b6282fd5dc84"   
  compute.googleapis.com/zone:  "us-central1-f"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/veryloudstatic/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fstderr"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-06-21T13:53:47.746443513Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "default"    
   project_id:  "veryloudstatic"    
   version_id:  "20190620t195308"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 textPayload:  "Cannot read property 'parsePath' of undefined
"  
 timestamp:  "2019-06-21T13:53:45Z"  
}




 35.233.167.246 - "GET /" 500 148 "-" "GoogleStackdriverMonitoring-UptimeChecks(https://cloud.google.com/monitoring)"
Expand all | Collapse all {
 httpRequest: {
  latency:  "0.166s"   
  referer:  "-"   
  remoteIp:  "35.233.167.246"   
  requestMethod:  "GET"   
  requestUrl:  "/"   
  responseSize:  "148"   
  status:  500   
  userAgent:  "GoogleStackdriverMonitoring-UptimeChecks(https://cloud.google.com/monitoring)"   
 }
 insertId:  "28alo0fexgmee"  
 jsonPayload: {…}  
 labels: {…}  
 logName:  "projects/veryloudstatic/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Fnginx.request"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-06-21T13:53:47.746443513Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 timestamp:  "2019-06-21T13:53:45.536Z"  
 trace:  "projects/veryloudstatic/traces/5190f7942330e15370ff65d1c79c5963"  
}
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback and the snippet of code triggering it.

Answer (score 0):

Without more of a stack trace its hard to tell, but check your dependency versions if there are any. An underlying dependency may have updated. Make sure to check both your app code and the CircleCI base image.

Comment: Thanks! Yes this is what I'm pursuing right now: different dependency versions after npm install, because of the "~" and "^" versions in package-lock.json...